# Sitecore ECM - [NonCriticalException]: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Today I have an exception with the ECM with the content/evidence as below :

```
[NonCriticalException]: Unable to connect to the remote server
```

My "SMTP.ConnectionStringName" no problem.

[image]

I cannot send mail, do you have any idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the preview frame tries to download the email content. You should check the RendererUrl field on the Manager Root item and verify that the server is capable of resolving that url sucessfully.

Comment: Thank you, I restart my IIS and problem was fixed !

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of things. I've had an issue in the past where software on the server was conflicting with ECM. If it was working before it's likely that something has changed on the server to cause this issue.

I would recommend following these steps on the Sitecore Knowledge base, which might get you a more meaningful error message:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/553662

If this doesn't achieve anything then contact Sitecore support.